# Select-Object on imported CSV column with space in name returned empty values

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm writing a script to process a CSV file created on a non-Windows platform.

The CSV has a lot of columns, not all of which I want.
They are:

```
   TypeName: System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject

Name
----
Equals
GetHashCode
GetType
ToString
AVGCPUTIME
AVG_CARDS_PN
AVG_CARDS_RD
AVG_ELAPSED
AVG_IO_TIME
AVG_LINES_PRNTD
AVG_OV_MEM
AVG_OV_MEM_INT
AVG_SAV_MEM
AVG_SAV_MEM_INT
BEGINDATE
BEGINTIME
CARDS_PN
CARDS_RD
CPUTIME
DCKEYIN
ELAPSED
ENDDATE
ENDTIME
IO_TIME
JOBNAME
JOBSTATUS
JOBTYPE
LINES_PRNTD
MANUAL
MIXNUM
OV_MEM
OV_MEM_INT
PCJOB
REFNUM
RUNTIME PARAMETERS            ...
SAV_MEM
SAV_MEM_INT
SCHEDDATE
SCHEDTIME
SYSTEM
TASKNUM
USERCODE
```

I have a problem selecting the property, `RUNTIME PARAMETERS` - both of the following bits of code result in me having a column with the name I expect, but every value in that column is empty (I'm using `Out-GridView` just now while writing the script, the final script will output data to a new file once I've filtered with `Where-Object` etc to pull out only the info I need - the intention is for the PowerShell script to run as an automated process when the file lands on the server).

```
$Inp = Import-Csv K:\LOGSTATS_ALLBATCH_20150602165021.CSV
$Inp| Select USERCODE,JOBNAME,MIXNUM,TASKNUM,BEGINDATE,BEGINTIME,ENDDATE,ENDTIME,DCKEYIN,MANUAL,JOBSTATUS,JOBTYPE,CPUTIME,IOTIME,ELAPSED,SYSTEM,"RUNTIME PARAMETERS"|OGV

$Inp = Import-Csv K:\LOGSTATS_ALLBATCH_20150602165021.CSV
$Inp| Select USERCODE,JOBNAME,MIXNUM,TASKNUM,BEGINDATE,BEGINTIME,ENDDATE,ENDTIME,DCKEYIN,MANUAL,JOBSTATUS,JOBTYPE,CPUTIME,IOTIME,ELAPSED,SYSTEM,@{Name="PARAMS";Expression={$_."RUNTIME PARAMETERS"}}|OGV
```

Here's a sample of the input:

```
"REFNUM","USERCODE","JOBNAME","MIXNUM","TASKNUM","BEGINDATE","BEGINTIME","ENDDATE","ENDTIME","SCHEDDATE","SCHEDTIME","DCKEYIN","MANUAL","PCJOB","JOBSTATUS","JOBTYPE","CPUTIME","AVGCPUTIME","IO_TIME","AVG_IO_TIME","ELAPSED","AVG_ELAPSED","SAV_MEM","AVG_SAV_MEM","OV_MEM","AVG_OV_MEM","SAV_MEM_INT","AVG_SAV_MEM_INT","OV_MEM_INT","AVG_OV_MEM_INT","LINES_PRNTD","AVG_LINES_PRNTD","CARDS_RD","AVG_CARDS_RD","CARDS_PN","AVG_CARDS_PN","SYSTEM","RUNTIME PARAMETERS"                                                                                                                                                                                 
01141730,TEST            ,CONTROLCARD                         ,09376,00000,20150601,0106,20150601,0106,20150601,0100,N,N,N,COMPLETEDOK ,SCHEDULED ,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,   0:00:00,   0:00:00,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,0000000000,01234,"BETA" "INCR" "ALL"
```

And here's an example of the output from the 2nd piece of code, piped through `Format-List`:

```
USERCODE  : TEST 
JOBNAME   : CONTROLCARD 
MIXNUM    : 09376
TASKNUM   : 00000
BEGINDATE : 20150601
BEGINTIME : 0106
ENDDATE   : 20150601
ENDTIME   : 0106
DCKEYIN   : N
MANUAL    : N
JOBSTATUS : COMPLETEDOK 
JOBTYPE   : SCHEDULED 
CPUTIME   : 0000000000
IOTIME    : 
ELAPSED   : 0:00:00
SYSTEM    : 01234
PARAMS    :
```

Any help understanding why I'm either not selecting the property with the space in it, or not seeing the values, would be greatly appreciated!
**EDIT:**
It seems the code was ok but there is a possible issue with the encoding of the header - adding screenshot from hex editor for @Ansgar Wiechers

[image]

Comment: Your sample input date works correctly for me. Check that the `RUNTIME PARAMETERS` field title doesn't have leading/trailing whitespace (or other weird characters).

Comment: No leading/trailing characters in the field title, however, looks like the space in the field title, isn't! It just looks like one. If I edit the CSV file to delete the space between RUNTIME and PARAMETERS and then enter the space myself and save the file, powershell has no issue with it!  I'll try forcing some encoding, otherwise I'll go check in a hex editor what that character really is, then I can do a gc on the file, do a replace, then out-file, then it should process ok

Comment: Bizarre, its an ASCII 32 (20 HEX) according to my hex editor so it shouldn't be objecting!

Comment: Hmm... can you provide the hex view of the entire `RUNTIME  PARAMETERS` header string? Are there perhaps zero-width unicode characters before or after the space (like U+200D)?

Comment: I've noticed that if I open the original file in notepad, then save it without having changed anything, it has the same effect as if I overwrite the space in RUNTIME PARAMETERS header field - all is good. I also tried playing with the various Encoding options of the Import-CSV command but to no avail. At the end of the header row it is null-filled to the end of the line (OD OA), whereas on the data rows, they are space filled until the end of the line - so I wonder if the nulls are the issue and notepad converts nulls to spaces...

Comment: Replacing all the nulls first works a treat, but it's sloooowwww..... - and ideas how to do it more quickly than `(gc K:\LOGSTATS_ALLBATCH_20150602165021.CSV) -replace $null,''|out-file K:\LOGSTATS_ALLBATCH_20150602165021.CSV -Force` ? -it's a 14Mb file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your input file contains null characters that mess up your field names. You can remove them like this:

```psh
$file = 'C:\path\to\your.csv'
(Get-Content $file -Raw) -replace [string][char]0 | Set-Content $file
```

Removing all null characters should be safe, since your file appears to be ASCII encoded (no BOM in your screenshot).

The removal operation took about a second when I tested it on a 13 MB sample file.

**Warning:** Do **NOT** use this on Unicode encoded files (UTF-8, UTF-16, ...) or you'll end up with gibberish in your files.

Comment: Excellent - much faster way of fixing the file! Cheers!